# Grails GORM 3.2.0 query with `where values in list`

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I upgraded my codebase from Grails 2.1.0 to 3.2.0. However, I encountered a situation that one of my queries did not work as expected.

```
public List<Location> findAllLocationsByNames(Collection<String> placeNames) {
        return Location.executeQuery("select l from Location l where l.placeName in (:placeNames)", [placeNames: placeNames])
}
```

Before upgrade, this query was working well. I passed in a collection of type `LinkedKeySet` (from `HashMap.getKeySet()`) and it returns correctly the list of locations. But now with new version of Grails I got this error:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I digged a bit deeper inside Grails and GORM and saw that QueryTranslatorImpl translated the named parameter `placeNames` to SQL AST as `[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=placeNames, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.StringType@49c72fb7}`, but I'm not sure why.

In the end, I changed the original query to use `where` and DetachedCriteria:

```
public List<Location> findAllLocationsByNames(Collection<String> placeNames) {
        return Location.where {placeName in placeNames}.list()
}
```

This time, everything works fine and the returned result was what I expected.

What is the problem with the first query using `executeQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems newer versions of Hibernate are less lenient if you specify parameters that are not of type `java.util.List` and instead are other collection types (`Set` etc.)

Comment: You're right, thanks! Do you know what exactly has changed there?